# How to not read a csv file if its being written to in that instance?

Tags: python, csv

Is this something that can be done in python or any language? Is there a way to detect if a csv file is being written to in that instantaneous moment?

Comment: Have you tried https://pypi.org/project/inotify/?

Comment: Your intent is not clear - do you want to read, but make sure the file has not changed while you were reading? Do you want to be notified when you the file changed, and reread it? Is the file being overwritten by the foreign process, or is it being appended to? You need to focus you question, with a clear explanation of what you want to do, and a skeleton code of what you tried, or where the code you are asking for help about should fit.

Comment: So imagine a scenario where a webpage is displaying information from this csv file. I do not want it displaying updated information if the write to the csv file hasn't completed i.e mid write. Is that clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to update the CSV file atomically. Starting to write over the existing file as you have realized is not atomic and will get you in trouble.

The trick is to write the new data to a temporary new file and then move the temp file over the live file. The move operation is atomic (for practical purposes).

```
create-new-csv-data > new-data.csv
mv new-data.csv data.csv
```

For probably more info than you want to know about how atomic a `mv` *really* is, see for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/322038/is-mv-atomic-on-my-fs.

Comment: This is an interesting suggestion that I'll have to look into. Thanks.